# check if one of the many middlewares exist laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.4, middleware

Can I check if one of the mentioned middleware exist in Laravel 5.4 route group? Proceed if condition meets for any of the middleware i.e. `user`, `manager` or `admin`

For example like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['user'|'manager'|'admin']], function () {
//
}
```

Comment: shouldn't middleware be separated by comma into array or pipe into a singular string? (My comment will not fix the problem, just curious)

Comment: yes you are right @manix but all the mentioned middleware should be passed to process further by this approach

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using only one middleware for all these roles. You could use in this middleware a parameter as is shown in example in Laravel's Docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#middleware-parameters)

Comment: otherwise you could also create one middleware which will check if any of these middleware is true

Comment: Yes, I am doing the same @milo526

Answer (score 0):

After wandering here and there, I decided to create a new middleware which matches similarities for all the middleware `user`, `manager` and `admin`

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can do that.**

To do that, create a Middleware with the name you want, so in the middleware add a property with name $roles (you can change the name if you want)

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $roles)
{
    try {
        $roles = explode(',', $roles);
        /**
         * Role is a user level. Check User Model, on level, has a full description of the roles.
         */
        $user = Auth::user();
        if (!in_array($user->level, $roles)) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Access Denied'], 403);
        }
        return $next($request);
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        Log::channel('middlewares')->error("Erro middleware Roles", [
            'roles' => $roles,
            'request_data' => $request->all(),
            'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            'file' => $e->getFile(),
            'line' => $e->getLine(),
        ]);
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Error'], 403);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Route::middleware(['roles:1,2'])->prefix('stores')->controller(AdminStoresController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'index');
    Route::post('/', 'store');
    Route::put('/{id}', 'update');
    Route::delete('/{id}', 'delete');
});
```